# Property-Binding of placeholder in the input-tag with two properties

Tags: html, angular, property-binding

I am wondering how to bind two properties to the placeholder of the input-tag.

This is working

```
<input type="text" [placeholder]="this.name" />
```

But how to get another property for example "this.forename" in the placeholder, so both properties are displayed with space inbetween?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Whatever you do with the placeholder, please add a `<label>` too.

Comment: I will, thanks for your advice!

Comment: Hey, please mark as answered.

Answer (score 2):

you can try:

```
<input type="text" [placeholder]="user.name + ' ' + user.forename" />
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u858fk)

Answer (score 0):

Interpolation `{{ }}` works better

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{{name}} {{forename}}" />
```

Also note that, you need not use `this` object within your template.

Comment: This works fine as well. Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: Why should you use string interpolation while property binding allows you to do the same thing? It's not the correct way, you should use property binding as it is the best practice.

```<input type="text" [placeholder]="name+' '+forename" />```

if it's an attribute of the tag, you can just use `attr.attributename="value"`
Ex: ```<td [attr.colspan]="dynamicValue">Hello</td>```